# Calling of subclass methods in heritance

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have a class Customer which inherits by class RichPerson and class PoorPerson..it is store in ArrayList cus... however , some of subclass methods are different and i'm unable to call the subclass methods when accessing Customer array list.. like cus.get(0).description..

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You must cast it to `RichPerson`:

```
RichPerson rp = (RichPerson) cus.get(0);
//you can use rp.description
```

To check the type you can use the `instanceof` operator:

```
if(cus.get(0) instanceof RichPerson) {
    RichPerson rp = (RichPerson) cus.get(0);
}
```

Comment: why is it downvoted ? it works..i read some posts saying its not encourage to do it ..